# The role of reinforcement learning in Economics

Tags: game-theory

While working on different research projects I got fascinated by RL which got applied to many fields that are focused on agent based modeling. Though it is a field in Machine Learning what interests me is the overlap between that apporach with problems in economics. The latest awesome paper I know is the "AI Economist" by [Socher et al.](https://arxiv.org/abs/2004.13332). Do you know more fields/papers where RL is applied to economic decision making? And do you think that this approach can lead to a paradigm shift in economics ?

Answer (score 5):

I would say applications of RL in economics are still in their infancy, though probably have applications in many state-based models, agent-based models, or fields with repeated interactions like game theory.

There has been some work done on what you might call the "microfoundations" part - which is studying "regret". Susan Athey, for example, does a lot of work in this space, and an example paper is "Policy Learning with Observational Data" found here: https://arxiv.org/abs/1702.02896

There are also some papers that shoes RL results converge to what one might obtain via rational expectations / equilibrium. For example, "Learning leads to bounded rationality and the evolution of cognitive bias in public goods games" by Leimar, O. & McNamara, J. M.

Comment: Thanks! Ill read that papers. To me it looks like RL is quite a low hanging fruit in economic research...

Answer (score 2):

Given the set-up of the problem in reinforcement learning there is also a relatively close link with evolutionary stable strategies in game theory. Granted evolutionary game theory is not economics per se, but there are overlaps.

See for example [this paper](https://www.jstor.org/stable/20118420?seq=1) by Tuyls et al. on the relation between multi agent systems, reinforcement learning and evolutionary game theory